# multi dimensional array creation

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array

being a beginner of perl i m not sure of the scope of perl. can somebody gimme a basic program for multi dimensional array creation n the full idea behind the code? thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4):

See chapter "Nested Data Structures" in the [Modern Perl book](http://www.onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/), and [perllol](http://p3rl.org/lol) and [perldsc](http://p3rl.org/dsc) in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

[perldoc perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html) has detailed explanation regarding nested arrays. See also [perldoc perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in Perl can only hold scalars. However, those scalars can be array references. Check out these two links (in this order), which helped refresh my own understanding. The perldoc link contains the canonical example code that will help you get started. Good luck!

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=90647

http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html

Answer (score 1):

daxim has the right stuff for most cases. In the rare case of doing purely numerical manipulation see  [PDL](http://pdl.perl.org) . PDL allows Perl to behave a little more like Matlab.

Again, If this doesn't ring any bells, see daxim's answer.